How to make permission for Bluetooth and Location on a mobile application by React Native?
I currently work on my academic project where I build mobile application using React Native. That need to get Bluetooth and Location for better performance.
I building application for Android devices, I ran my code on Expo Go as prototype.
Can I get the permission request in Expo Go for test is it work? If permission allowed while asking the device will actually ON the Bluetooth and Location?
If not, what is the best way to proceed this?
I need solution on this for clarification from those who work on it or know this?
I expect from you as the right way to make it and get the steps for build it.
